# Push notification device tokens and their validity

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a general question to device tokens for push notifications.

**this is a part of the apple documentation:**

> A device token is not a unique ID that you can use to identify a
>   device. Device tokens can change after updating the operating system
>   on a device. As a result, apps should send their device token

I understood that each app on a device get an unique token.
For example, the token of a app on my device is XYZ

With this token I can send from my server an push notification to XYZ and I will received it on my device.

According to Apple, the device token can change after an OS update 
but what happens if the device token of my device changes and I don't start the app for a few days, so that the new device token isn't in my token table in my database?

What will be happen with the notification, which I will send to the old device token?

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html , but I guess the token is updated only when you launch the app. Until then the token you already have in your db is still valid.

Comment: yes this is the documentation which i had read.
but this is the problem. how can i solve the problem with the days between the point "device token had change" and "user start the app to submit the new token"?